Applescript application disappears from login items after running once
I have an AppleScript application (i.e. an AppleScript exported as an application) in my "Login Items" list which disappears from the list after running once.
The script itself is simple:
delay 20 
tell application "Dropbox" to activate 

My dropbox is on an external drive, this gives the drive time to mount before Dropbox looks for it.
The script works---waits 20 seconds and then launches Dropbox---when I run it from Script Editor, when clicked, and on the first restart after it is added to the list of Login Items in System Settings. The issue is that after running once it is removed from the list which is not the desired behavior.
